# WebStorm LESS Filewatcher Could not find RubyGem less

Tags: less, osx-mountain-lion, ruby-1.9.3, webstorm

I'm getting this error trying to use the WebStorm LESS File Watcher

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:777:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem less (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:211:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1056:in `gem'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/lessc:18
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14
```

I'm running OSX Mountain Lion

How do I fix it?

**EDIT:**

I did this...

```
gem install less
Successfully installed less-2.3.2
1 gem installed
```

Didn't help.

**EDIT 2:**

I fiddled with the path in the LESS Filewatcher setup panel

and now I get this

```
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/lessc --no-color bootstrap.less
env: ruby_noexec_wrapper: No such file or directory
```

It feels like progress, but alas I'm not compiling less to css yet.

Comment: `Could not find RubyGem less`: have you installed a `less` gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok what I did was this

With rvm remove all other versions of ruby

```
rvm remove 2.0.0-p195
```

Install this gem in the system version of ruby

```
sudo gem install rubygems-bundler
```

install the less gem

```
sudo gem install less
sudo gem install therubyracer
```

I am sure someone can give me a better way of doing this but this ruby thing has a pretty steep learning curve that I really am not interested in pursuing.

This is the way I did it...if someone wants to contribute a better way please share here to save someone else the 4 hours I just lost to it.

Comment: Same problem, still didn't find a better way to do it without removing the latest ruby with rvm. :(

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to remove any ruby version. Just switch to the system version of ruby and install the compiler.

```
rvm use system
sudo gem install less
rvm use default
```